# Reacting to broadcast from another process

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

I have class that looks like this:

```
package com.broadcast;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class BroadcastActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public void tasterPritisnut(View target) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("akcija");
    intent.putExtra("message", "Hello Valakar");
    this.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
}
```

This is broadcast class. Manifest class is:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".BroadcastActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Now I have created a new project with new class:

```
package com.reciever;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class Reciever4 extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String poruka = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    Log.d("", poruka + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
}
}
```

This is receiver class, and manifest file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.reciever"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <receiver android:name=".Reciever4">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="akcija"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I installed both applications, but when I send broadcast, nothing is printed in log. I have build this similar to Apress book example, but cant get it to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Quick thought: do you need to call [setAction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setAction%28java.lang.String%29) on your intent?  This [webpage](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/) has an example where they call setAction if you want an example.

FYI, you should name your intents with a full package name like "com.yourdomain.yourapp.yourintent" (although I think it is unlikely that this is causing your problem).

The [API docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/action-element.html) for the `<action>` element say:

> For actions you define, it's best to use the package name as a prefix
>   to ensure uniqueness.